# Runtime of this loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I need some advice on how to determine the runtime of this loop :

```
s=0 
 for ( i=1 , i <= 2^m ; i=i*2 ) { 
   s++ 
}
return s
```

With

$C_1$ =  actions performed once before entering the loop and
$C_2$ = actions performed one after entering the loop,

I see that $T(m) = C_1 + C_2 \cdot 2^m$.

How can I  determine $T(m)$?

Comment: You *did* determine $T(m)$ already, but your result is wrong. Mind how `i` is changed after each iteration.

Comment: k = number of times we enter the loop .  i = 1 k =1 ; i =2 k =2 i =4 k=3 i=8 , k=4 , i=16 , k=5 , i=32 k=6 .

Comment: T(m) = C1 + C2*(m+1) ?